# How to dynamically compose an OR query filter in Django to delete pairs of objects from ManyToManyFields?

Tags: django, many-to-many

if i want to implement this for delete multiple object from many to many field i need to create a dynamic filter like the below one.

```
PizzaToppingRelationship = Pizza.toppings.through
PizzaToppingRelationship.objects.filter(
    Q(pizza=my_pizza, topping=pepperoni) |
    Q(pizza=your_pizza, topping=pepperoni1) |
    Q(pizza=your_pizza2, topping=mushroom)
).delete()
```

However, I want to create this query filter from a list of query objects. How to do that?

e.g. [{"pizza": <my_pizza>, "topping": }, {"pizza": <your_pizza>, "topping": }, {"pizza": <your_pizza2>, "topping": }]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert this into a `Q` object:

```
from django.db.models import Q

data = [
    {'pizza': my_pizza, 'topping': pepperoni},
  , {'pizza': your_pizza, 'topping': pepperoni1}
  , {'pizza': your_pizza2, 'topping': mushroom}
]

PizzaToppingRelationship = Pizza.toppings.through
PizzaToppingRelationship.objects.filter(
    Q(*[Q(**dati) for dati in data], _connector=Q.OR)
).delete()
```

Comment: its throwing error like 'Q' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: @FariaNawrine: Yes, I forgot an asterisk. Updated.